# How can I move a Google Sites website to GitHub pages?

Tags: google-classic-sites, github-pages

I am trying to move all of my site from Google Sites to GitHub Pages. Is there a way to let me do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a web crawler/scraper like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) to download your entire website as a folder of HTML, CSS, image, and other files.

Once you've got your website downloaded, you can [commit and push all of those files to a GitHub repository](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) and [set up GitHub Pages to serve that repository as a website](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/#setup).

You might also need to fix some links and references throughout your site (e.g. update the website address, if you're changing addresses).